# App crashes on swipe delete action sometimes in Xcode (Swift)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, crash

My to do list app crash **sometimes** when i do swipe for delete action.

Logs show following message :

**ibobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 11, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)**

My code for delete on swipe action

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
        if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete) {

            toDoList.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            toDoListTable.reloadData()
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(toDoList, forKey: "toDoList")




        }
    }
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: is it when deleting the first or last item ? Check your bounds...

Comment: I'm not familiar with xCode, but with an error like that, I would wonder if there wasn't a permissions issue. Perhaps trying to access a bit of memory/storgae that is locked by another thread?

Comment: `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` is resulted when accessing memory that doesn't exist. Are you accessing an existing element in `toDoList`? Try putting a breakpoint right before `toDoList.removeAtIndex` and `po` the item to be removed

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html) you should call

`- (void)deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation: (UITableViewRowAnimation)animation;`

Below is the sample code from Apple Documentation. Notice that it remove the item from data source first. Then perform the `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths: withRowAnimation:`

Give it a try

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
// If row is deleted, remove it from the list.
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    [toDoList removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
```